# How do I iterate the list and copy the files from machineB and machineC efficiently?

Tags: bash, shell, scp, file-copy

I need to scp the files from `machineB` and `machineC` to `machineA`. I am running my below shell script from `machineA`. I have setup the ssh keys properly.

If the files are not there in `machineB`, then it should be there in `machineC`.

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly PRIMARY=/data01/primary/.
readonly FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
readonly MAPPED_LOCATION=/bat/data/snapshot
PARTITION=(0 3 5 7 9)

dir1=20131222
dir2=20131222

scp david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/weekly_1980_[$el]_200003_5.data $PRIMARY || scp david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/weekly_1980_[$el]_200003_5.data $PRIMARY
```

Now my question is if you take a look into my above scp command, I have `[$el]`, I need to replace this with `PARTITION`, which means I need to iterate `PARTITION` and replace `[$el]` with each number in PARTITION.

So my scp command should look like this if I iterate `PARTITION` -

```
scp david@machineB:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_0_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_0_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.

scp david@machineB:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_3_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_3_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.

scp david@machineB:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_5_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_5_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.

scp david@machineB:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_7_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_7_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.

scp david@machineB:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_9_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_9_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.
```

1. How do I iterate PARTITION in such a way, so that I can make the
   above SCP command?
2. And as you can see, I am copying the files one by one into `machineA` `/data01/primary/` folder. Is there any better way of doing this? Meaning, can I copy all the files together in one shot instead of doing it one by one?

Answer (score 1):

To copy all the partitions, use a wildcard:

```
scp david@machineB:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_*_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_*_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.
```

If you to copy only partitions 0, 3, 5, 7 , 9, then use:

```
scp david@machineB:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_[03579]_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_[03579]_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.
```

If the partition list is specified by a variable, the simplest would be:

```
PARTITION=03579
scp david@machineB:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_[$PARTITION]_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_[$PARTITION]_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.
```

If it is specified in an array:

```
PARTITION=(0 3 5 7 9)
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=""
scp david@machineB:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_["${PARTITION[*]}"]_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_["${PARTITION[*]}"]_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.
IFS="$oldIFS"
```

Comment: Thanks John, I cannot use wild card here because I need to copy only those files that are there in the PARTITION list only. In that case, what change I am supposed to make in my above shell script?

Comment: @TechGeeky Do you need to specify PARTITION as a bash array?  Could you specify it just as easily as `PARTITION=03579` ?

Comment: Actually that partition has to be passed by Python script. So currently I am in the impression that I will be passing in the form of bash arrays and I haven't decided yet.. And in general number of elements in the bash arrays will be `420`... And also if I need to do it one by one, then how I should do that as well?

Comment: Python has much better looping and string handling constructs than bash.  If this is all being controlled by a python script, I would have python create the `scp` command and feed it to subprocess for execution.

Comment: Thanks a lot John. I will try to see whether I should do all these things in Python or not. And also, can you explain little bit on your solution for array? You are using IFS something which I am not aware of..

Comment: When an array is displayed, the elements are separated by the first character in the IFS variable.  Since I wanted the PARTITION array to display as a 03579 for pathname expansion, I set it to empty.  In general, when bash decides what characters to treat as whitespace, bash examines the value of IFS.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12134/discussion-between-techgeeky-and-john1024)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly PRIMARY=/data01/primary/.
readonly FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
readonly MAPPED_LOCATION=/bat/data/snapshot

for i in 0 3 5 7 9
do
    scp david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/weekly_1980_${i}_200003_5.data PRIMARY || scp david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/weekly_1980_${i}_200003_5.data $PRIMARY
done
```

Answer (score 1):

To efficiently copy many files at once, use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) instead of `scp`. Rsync uses the SSH connection to transfer files remotely.

```
rsync_filter=()
for el in "${PARTITION[@]}"; do
  rsync_filter+=(--include="weekly_1980_${el}_200003_5.data")
done
for machine in "${FILERS_LOCATION[@]}"; do
  rsync -a "${rsync_filter[@]}" --exclude='*' "david@$machine:$dir1/" "$PRIMARY/"
done
```

Rsync will skip copying if the files are already present with the same size and modification time (you can configure this).

Alternatively, forget all about the fact that they're remote copies. Mount the remote filesystem with [SSHFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS), and proceed as you would copy local files.

```
mkdir machineB machine C
sshfs david@machineB: machineB
sshfs david@machineC: machineC
for el in "${PARTITION[@]}"; do
  cp -p "machineB/$dir1/weekly_1980_${el}_200003_5.data" "$PRIMARY/" ||
  cp -p "machineC/$dir1/weekly_1980_${el}_200003_5.data" "$PRIMARY/"
done
```

You can even do one better and make a [union mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount) of the two machines. A union mount joins two directory trees into one, such that accessing a file from the union tree tries inside one tree first, and if the file is not present tries the same location in the other tree instead.

```
mkdir union
mount -t aufs -o dirs=$PWD/machineB:$PWD/machineC machineB+machineC union
for el in "${PARTITION[@]}"; do
  cp -p "union/$dir1/weekly_1980_${el}_200003_5.data" "$PRIMARY/"
done
```